# Drag and drop email attachement to library (explorer view) failing

Tags: document-library, attachments, internet-explorer, explorer-view

For some of my users, but not all, when they drag and drop an attachment (tested with both .pdf and .docx) into the explorer view window of a document library it appears to copy it over, but in fact the size of the file in the doc library is 0kb. So the doc icon and title appear, but the document isnt really there...
These users can reset all their Internet Explorer (IE9) factory settings and it will temporarily correct the issue. But it will soon return.

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several causes for incorrect functioning of the Explorer view.

Some things you can check:

- Make sure you have enabled and started the “web client” service on the client machine (services.msc->web client);
- Try adding the site to the Trusted Sites zone.

More information about the Explorer view, the WebDav and FPRPC protocol can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/manjesh/archive/2010/01/03/all-about-explorer-view-in-sharepoint.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have opened the File explorer through 'Open with Explorer' in IE the above steps you have mentioned must work without any additional configurations.

If you are open to commercial tools you can try PageLight, which will allow [Drag and Drop of Attachments to SharePoint](http://www.sai-innovations.com/save-emails-attachments-sharepoint.aspx)

P.S: I am associated with PageLight